# Use image_tabular (python github package) on Colab

Tags: python, image, tuples, conv-neural-network, tabular

I'm using **Python** through Google **Colab**, and I would like to use a github package, **image_tabular**, in order to include tabular data information within a CNN image classifier.

https://github.com/naity/image_tabular

But I don't manage to correctly import the package from github to colab, and use its functionnality.

```
# clone package repository
!git clone https://github.com/naity/image_tabular.git

# navigate to atalaia directory
%cd image_tabular

!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall image_tabular

from image_tabular.core import *
   # NameError: name 'Tuple' is not defined
```

I don't know how to interpret this error, does anyone have a tip/comment? Is it possible that the github package didn't correctly import?

```
tab_data = (TabularList.from_df(tab_df, path = data_path, cat_names = cat_names, procs = procs).label_from_df(cols = ycol))
╭───────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ──────────────────────╮
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2882 │
│ in run_code                                                                  │
│                                                                              │
│   2879 │   │   │   try:                                                      │
│   2880 │   │   │   │   self.hooks.pre_run_code_hook()                        │
│   2881 │   │   │   │   #rprint('Running code', repr(code_obj)) # dbg         │
│ ❱ 2882 │   │   │   │   exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)     │
│   2883 │   │   │   finally:                                                  │
│   2884 │   │   │   │   # Reset our crash handler in place                    │
│   2885 │   │   │   │   sys.excepthook = old_excepthook                       │
│ <ipython-input-88-9b2e6c7077ac>:1 in <module>                                │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

   # NameError: name 'TabularList' is not defined
```

Thank you.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe it need other module to install before `image_tabular` - I checked source code and `Tuple` can be part of [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) module. OR maybe it need to install with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I checked source code and I don't see `TabularList` in module `image_tabular`. It uses module `fastai.tabular` but I don't see `TabularList` in this module too.

Comment: in this repo there are few `Jupyter Notebook` files and they import all from `image_tabular` - not only `core` - and also `fastai`. See [siim_isic_tabular_only.ipynb](https://github.com/naity/image_tabular/blob/master/siim_isic_tabular_only.ipynb)